# What would be the most cost effective camera solution for CubeSat satellite

Tags: cubesat, camera, remote-sensing

Commercial cubesat cameras are a bit expensive:
 http://www.cubesatshop.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=63&category_id=16&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=80

So what are the experiences with using cheaper commercial off-the-shelf cameras regarding radiation and low temperatures in LEO.

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, you might want to ask the right people. I have my doubts that you can find all of them here right now. I suggest you join this mailing list: http://www.cubesat.org/index.php/about-us/how-to-join There, you basically find members of most cubesat-projects in existence. From experience, quiet a lot of projects did a lot of interesting stuff, but the level of documentation is usually rather low. So there is basically no way around asking the people directly.

EDIT: If you receive a good answer, I would be glad if you could post it here!

Comment: By coincidence I landed here three years later to the day. The `/how-to-join` part of the link no longer works. Is this now the equivalent? [http://www.cubesat.org/mailinglist/](http://www.cubesat.org/mailinglist/)